# Can't properly remove nested xml tags with Python using xml minidom

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, tags, minidom

I am trying  to remove some nested tags of xml represented as string using Python 3.8 and built in xml.dom.minidom. Result is surprising, parser removes only first or opened tag and leaves closed tag. Surely I am missing something, but I can't see what it is.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xml

StringXML = "<root><test1><test2></test2></test1><test1><test2></test2></test1><test1><test2></test2></test1><test1><test2></test2></test1></root>"

a = xml.parseString(StringXML)
num = 0

while (a.getElementsByTagName('test2').length > num):
  if(a.getElementsByTagName('test2')[num]):

    a.getElementsByTagName('test2')[num].parentNode.removeChild(a.getElementsByTagName('test2')[num])
    a.getElementsByTagName('test2')[num].unlink()
  num = num +1

print(a.toxml())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove all `test2` elements, there is no need to increment a counter. Just iterate over the items returned by `getElementsByTagName('test2')`.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xml

StringXML = "<root><test1><test2></test2></test1><test1><test2></test2></test1><test1><test2></test2></test1><test1><test2></test2></test1></root>"

a = xml.parseString(StringXML)

for test2 in a.getElementsByTagName('test2'):
    test2.parentNode.removeChild(test2)

# Need to add empty text node to get <test1></test1> serialization
for test1 in a.getElementsByTagName('test1'):
    test1.appendChild(a.createTextNode(''))

print(a.toprettyxml())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <test1></test1>
    <test1></test1>
    <test1></test1>
    <test1></test1>
</root>
```

Comment: Still not having what I what, I would like result with open and closed tags, like <test1><test1>

Comment: Note that from an XML point of view, `<test1/>` is exactly the same as `<test1></test1>`.

Comment: In future I will try to use etree. Minidom is a bit confusing. I am not python dev, as you can see :-)